# Create a Wordpress Contact Form to call a POST AWS API Gateway and send user data

Tags: php, javascript, api

I am working for a company, and I need to create a Wordpress contact form to call an AWS Api Gateway with a POST Request, but the API function needs to get some parameters:

Domain;
SecurityKey (each user needs this key);
ContentID (The contentID of the page, it's from different articles, so each article have an ID);
UserID (the logged user ID);
FormEmail (the email that the user will fill in the contact form);
UserSession;
FormFullName;
FormUserMessage;
UserPageURL;
I am struggling to find any answers on how to get these parameters from a WP contact form.

We are using Wordpress, AWS Lambada Api Gateway, and Simple Email Service to send the email to the sponsor of the Article. I need a way to get the UserId, UserSession, SecurityKey params when the user is logged in our platform.

Until now, I am able to send the Form Data (Name, Email, Message), but I do not want the user to type the Session, ID, SecurityKey. I tested creating these form fields own my own and submitting the form, and it does work, but I want it to get these values automatically when the user logs in.

This is the code I have now:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function submitToAPI(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var URL = "https://iwczdv2u40.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Production/transactions";
    
                var Namere = /[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z]/;
                if (!Namere.test(jQuery("#FormFullName").val())) {
                             alert ("Name can not less than 2 char");
                    return;
                }
                
                if (jQuery("#FormEmail").val()=="") {
                    alert ("Please enter your email id");
                    return;
                }
    
                var reeamil = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;
                if (!reeamil.test(jQuery("#FormEmail").val())) {
                    alert ("Please enter valid email address");
                    return;
                }
    
           var FormFullName = jQuery("#FormFullName").val();
           var FormEmail = jQuery("#FormEmail").val();
           var UserMessage = jQuery("#UserMessage").val();
           var data = {
              FormFullName : FormFullName,
              FormEmail : FormEmail,
              UserMessage : UserMessage                  
            };
    
           jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url : "https://iwczdv2u40.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Production/transactions",
             dataType: "json",
             crossDomain: "true",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
    
             
             success: function () {
               // clear form and show a success message
               alert("Thank you for your review. It will be posted shortly.");
               document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
           location.reload();
             },
             error: function () {
               // show an error message
               alert("Error.");
             }});
         }
    </script>
</head>

<form id="contact-form" method="post">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <input type="text" style="height:35px;" id="FormFullName" placeholder="Enter name here…" class="form-control" /><br/>
      <h4>Email:</h4>
      <input type="email" style="height:35px;" id="FormEmail" placeholder="Enter email here…" class="form-control"/><br/>
      <h4>How can we help you?</h4>
      <textarea id="UserMessage" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></textarea><br/>
      <button type="button" onClick="submitToAPI(event)" class="btn btn-lg" style="margin-top:20px;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Edit: I don't know how it works, but I don't want people to be able to inspect element on the form and see these hidden fields.

PS: we are not using a serverless website yet, we are changing to it in a near future.

Thanks!

Comment: You say you want to get them automatically, but where from? What are they? Those aren't things that come from WordPress.

Comment: You'd have to obtain them from the User meta_data, but first you have to get them all into the user meta_data; once in there you can extract them using `get_user_meta()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/ and just add them all into hidden fields on the form. Then your JS can pull the values from the hidden fields.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Got it... but one question, if the values will be in hidden fields on the form, does it mean that any person can inspect element on the form and see the values, and maybe change them? That is the only problem. Sorry, I am a Junior Web Developer, so I am learning stuff

Comment: @JacobPeattie exactly, that is my question, I am a beginner, so I don't know where to get these values, maybe a function that receives all user data like a unique User ID.

Comment: Guillherme, in theory yes; but an important thing to remember is that the hidden fields ONLY get populated or even created IF the user is logged in, and they ONLY contain an individual user's data. You're asking about the `UserId, UserSession, SecurityKey', so they would be my ID, my Session and my SecurityKey if I'm the one logged in - now, why would I want to change them and even if I wanted to, what are the chances I am going to know someone else's info?  You could look at encrypting them, hashing them, etc. but that may not be worth the effort depending on what you're doing.

Comment: What you would do is 'check if the user is logged in', if they are, 'get their meta data, then get all 3 of the values you mention'.  Then conditionally generate the hidden field like so `if( !empty( $securityKey ) ) : echo '<input type="hidden" id="sec_key" name="sec_key" value="' . $securityKey . '"/>'; endif;`
Now, if I check developer tools and inspect the element, yeah, I can see it, but it's my info.
Another alternative would be to run your API Call via AJAX, then you'd get the user info in the PHP function & transmit it across, so now someone would have to check the network panel.

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding what your objective is.

Comment: @TonyDjukic that's the answer I was looking for! Your explanation makes sense for me now. All this information would be when the user is logged in. I will have to learn how to use PHP with forms then, but that answers me a lot of things, thanks for that!